# PyQt4 and Python 3.2 on OS X

Tags: pyqt4

I've successfully installed Qt4.7.3, Python 3.2, SIP, & PyQt4. Or I think I do? I can 

`import PyQt4`
 without any issues but when I try to run this:
`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.resize(250, 150)
widget.setWindowTitle('simple')
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())

I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./simple.py", line 6, in <module>

    from PyQt4 import QtGui

ImportError: cannot import name QtGui`

I've checked the paths and they seem to be fine but when looking for the components I can't find them? I do have libQt.a and libQtCore.a where I assume those components would be. I just can't seem to access them.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` you can not be sure which version of python starts up. For testing you should directly use `python3.2`!

Since `import PyQt4` works and `from PyQt4 import QtGui` not, it is likely that the files in the PyQt4 module directory are misplaced.

The `QtGui.so` file needs to resist directly in the PyQt4 directory!

On GNU Systems this directory can be found at `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/` and on Windows at `%SystemDrive%23/Python32/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/`.

This might help finding the directory on Mac OS:

```
import PyQt4
print(PyQt4.__file__)
```